# How to calculate hash value for pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, linked-list

I want to create a hash table where I can store value with pointers as key.
For example In C++ if we define a linked list as:

```
struct Node{
 int val;
 Node* next;
}
```

I can create a hash table with pointers of `Node` using `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` like:

```
unordered_map<Node*,int> um;
Node* a = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
um[a]=12;
cout<<um[a]<<endl //This prints 12
```

Now if I want to do this without the standard library how can I calculate the hash value for `Node` pointers?

Comment: First you need to define your hashing function.

Comment: [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: If you are writing your hash implementation, you may find [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx) useful.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux perhaps we just edit and use `"C++ containers"` instead of `"STL"`? (which is what I take it to mean...)

Comment: Side note: In C++ `malloc` carries some risk. It does not call constructors so complicated objects are left as ticking time-bombs, ready to explode as soon as you try to use them improperly initialized. Users of the code will likely use `delete` to instead of `free` to release the allocation, and Crom only knows how that will turn out.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Answer (score 5):

Cast them to `uintptr_t` and then calculate the hash values for integers.

Comment: One more bit of useful information: The above works because pointers should already be unique identifiers. If they aren't you have other problems.